# When will QGIS use the WMS supplied legend images ? is there a workaround?

Tags: qgis, wms, legend

I use a lot of wms services with complicated maps : a legend is essential.
Qgis displays none of those legends. The URL is quoted in the metadata.

example 
WMS

http://geo.agiv.be/ogc/wms/product/ANB?/Grnkrt13

layer "Groenkaart Vlaanderen 2013"

legend url : 
http://geo.agiv.be/ogc/wms/product/ANB?request=GetLegendGraphic%26version=1.3.0%26format=image/png%26layer=Grnkrt13

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. What issue are you facing? What have you tried so far to resolve the issue?

Comment: i have a map with several colors fi dark green = tree; grey = urban area; light green = pastures ; ...
In the layer window i cannot display these categories while the link is indicated in the metadata

Answer (score 1):

Try this experimental QGIS plugin: CSI WMS Legend

(On option tab set search for "experimental")
[image]

The plugin Displays the GetLegendGraphic image of the selected WMS layer. The plugin has worked with several WMS I've tried. But with the WMS you specify it did not work.

[image]

Comment: i know this plugin and have been using it in qgis v 1.8

Comment: sadly until this moment it does not work in qgis v 2.0 nor in the dev version 2.1 - wil this plugin be adapted ?